# Ubuntu machine as gateway does not provide dns service

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns, gateway

i am trying to create a gateway using ubuntu server to provide normal firewall services, nat, hdcp and dns to the network. Firewall (ufw) works fine, as is nat (connected machines have internet access) and dhcp. The machines, however, are not able to solve the ip (example I can ping 8.8.8.8 but not google.com). The whole system is built on VM and as a test I created a subnet with a different address from the "normal" one to simulate the difference between internet and LAN.
I followed several guides found online using ufw as a firewall, isc-dchp for the dchp, iptables for the nat.
any idea why the dns is not working?
am I forgetting something essential?

Comment: Forgot to install and run a dns server/forwarder?

Comment: yeah i feel a little dumb now. I do a test and see if it works